# Can the Intel HAXM API be used outside of QEMU?

Tags: c, virtualization, intel, qemu, haxm

The [Intel HAXM driver](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) enables KVM-like abilites on Mac OSX and Windows, but at the moment, it appears to only be used by [Android's QEMU fork](https://github.com/android/platform_external_qemu/tree/master/target-i386). The API also has a couple of QEMU-specific structures and IOCTLs (`hax_qemu_version` and `HAX_VM_IOCTL_NOTIFY_QEMU_VERSION`).

So does the HAXM driver only work with QEMU? Or can I utilize it in a different project?

Comment: Any further progress? I am also interested in using HAXM for game console emulations.

Comment: Sadly, no. Like the answer says, HAXM wasn't designed for general-purpose virtualization, so I decided not to base a project on unsupported technology. On Windows, you might want to consider the Hyper-V APIs. OSX now includes a hypervisor API that looks very similar to HAXM.

Comment: I also thought to consider Hyper-V but I fail to find any projects doing so or concrete documentation on the API I need: I'm programming C++ code. The only thing I could find is how to manage VM images - which is not exactly I want to do. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: @hlide: Yeah, there isn't much in the way of example code when it comes to Hyper-V, but Microsoft documented the "hypercall" interface [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5805). It's fairly low-level, but with it, you can start and stop VMs (Hyper-V calls them "partitions", not to be confused with disk partitions), map memory into the VM's address space, handle interrupts, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation.

Comment: The Hyper-V API document is no longer available at this link. Do you know where I could find it back?

Comment: @hlide: The Wayback Machine has it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140519065644/http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/5/2/45275C52-93A9-4A29-BDBC-45DC1C82BC1D/Hypervisor%20Top%20Level%20Functional%20Specification%20v1.0.docx). Unfortunately, I discovered that the fun hypercalls can only be made from kernel mode in the root partition, so it doesn't look like Hyper-V can be used to achieve the same kind of userspace-controlled virtualization that KVM and Hypervisor.framework can do. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was a good question and since no one was jumping in, I posted it on the [Intel Android Forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/507158). You might want to jump on to that thread to further the discussion if you are still interested in the answer.

Here is the answer that Josh Provided:

HAXM is "officially" supported on the following platforms:

Windows 8 (32/64-bit), Windows 7 (32/64-bit), Windows Vista* (32/64-bit), Windows XP (32-bit only) and Mac OS X 10.6 and later (32/64-bit)

For HAXM on Linux, the basic instructions for setting it up under Linux (Ubuntu is assumed) are here:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-gingerbread-emulator

As HAXM was built to use QEMU, and specifically, to work with the Android Virtual Device Manager, which is part of the Android SDK, it's not really a general purpose virtualization tool.

Without more context to the original question you reposted from StackOverflow (i.e., how is the developer thinking about using HAXM outside of QEMU?), I don't think we have enough information to say one way or the other whether what they have in mind will work.

My answer would be "try it and see". If they're looking for an officially supported usage, though, that's limited to the OSes described above.

Hope that helps - let me know if you have more questions, or need more info.

Comment: Thanks for reposting the link. I probably should have asked there in the first place. For those wondering: HAX does indeed appear to work outside of the QEMU process, but it's not an officially-supported use case.